# Why is my Devops pipleline being triggered by the completion of another pipeline, despite me replacing the pipeline trigger with a schedule only

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have a pipeline that is being automatically triggered upon completion of another pipline despite me removing the code from the YAML that should be responsible for this.

Taking it back to the beginning: I have created 3 yaml Pipelines. Originally Pipeline 1 was configured for a Scheduled Trigger only. Pipeline 2 was triggered by completion of Pipeline 1.  Pipeline 3 was triggered by completion of Pipeline 2.  These pipeline triggers were defined in the yaml.  Below is an example of the relevant snippet from Pipeline 3's "original" yaml

```
trigger: none   

resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: Pipeline2 .
    source: Pipeline2 
    trigger: 
      branches:
        include: 
        - integration
```

However I then decided that I did not want to do this, and I removed the above code block and replaced it with the below:

```
trigger: none         

schedules:
- cron: "35 1 * * 1-5"
  displayName: Daily Schedule
  branches:
    include:
    - main
  always: true
```

Below shows that no triggers have been configured via the GUI
[image]

However Pipeline 3 is still being triggered by completion of Pipeline 2....Can someone please help me understand why my Pipeline is triggered by anything other than the schedule?

Below is a screenshot of the build summary
[image]

Comment: Did you push the code? Did you merge it into `main`?

Comment: Are pipeline2 and pipeline3 in the same repo? Is the YAML file of pipeline3 under your repo's default branch? Can you share a screenshot of the build Summary page when pipeline3 is triggered by pipeline2?

Comment: @DanielMann Yes my code has been merged with main

Comment: @ZiyangLiu-MSFT Hi Pipeline 1 & 2 operate in a branch called Integration.  Pipeline 3 is in main.  I'd hoped Pipeline 2 in integration would trigger Pipeline 3 in main.  It didnt work this way...hence i am trying to undo this and set schedules instead. I have added the screenshot above.

Comment: @ZiyangLiu-MSFT I have just updated the code for the Pipeline Trigger in the yaml above.  It didnt represent my actual code.  It is now correct referencing -integration which is what was really in my code.  Regardless I deleted this so cant work out why it is still triggering

Comment: Did you merge the changes to the `integration` branch? Pipelines should be running out of the same branch. If you're making permanent changes in a branch that never merges back to the trunk, you're not really using Git properly.

Comment: @DanielMann My code has been merged across all branches and is identical in all branches.  The issue is that in none of the branches (because the code is the same across all) is there any longer a reference to a pipeline trigger...but still my pipeline 3 triggers on completion of Pipeline 2....surely it should only ever receive a schedule trigger based upon the excerpt i have shared above?

Comment: @Nick Hall Please check if there is a YAML file under the "**integration**" branch with the same name as the one used to run pipeline3 under the main branch. If there is, please check whether this file has deleted the pipeline resource.  Then please go to pipeline3 ->More action -> Triggers ->YAML -> Get sources. Please check "**Default branch for manual and scheduled builds**" is main or integration.

Comment: @ZiyangLiu-MSFTYes I have done this there is no yaml in any branch with the pipeline trigger in the yaml...this is my problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this.  It appears to have been a bug.  When I updated my YAML to remove the pipeline trigger block and merged it across all the branches, Devops appears not to have updated my pipeline to remove this trigger.

To fix the problem I simply deleted the pipeline and recreated it, pointing at exactly the same YAML file and setting exactly the same default branch.  I did nothing else and now my pipeline is no longer being triggered by another pipeline

Comment: Since you have resolved your issue, it's suggested that you accept your answer above according to [How does accepting an answer work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235), so that others having the same issue can easily know the solution.

Comment: Possibly the fix for some of us is to add 'trigger: none' instead of having no trigger element at all.